# HIghcharts Treemap Groupby leaf objects at Level 1(Parent) and group by child at Level1(Sub objects)with custom color coding

Tags: highcharts

I have managed to create a Tree Map from High charts but I am stuck with achieving the following points,

Option 1: Enable Labels only at their respective Levels see the image attached
Option 2: Custom Colour Coding per cause per cause name 
Option 3: Group Coloured Border to indicate the grouping 
Option 4: First level should show only the cause(NI, SEC,CC) rather showing Regions which should be aggregated of the child nodes see the image for more understanding

Click the link https://photos.app.goo.gl/fUleBrR5OWfdgyiQ2 for Demonstratives image

Please find the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/mailsakthi/hj642eng/2/

Options 5: How to enable Different Labels at different Levels (Level 1 and Level 3 only should show at Level 1) Different permutation and combinations of enabling. Can I mention the same with the lables options.

```
levels: [{
            level: 1,  // 1,3 or 2,3 etc. more than 1 label
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                         }
        }]
```

Let me know if I can be of any further information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Leafs hierarchy and data labels**

`allowDrillToNode` only zooms to a clicked group. You want to change a data hierarchy and values (the data tree changes) so you should rearrange your code and use the concept of **drilldowns**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/drilldown

---

**Creating borders**

Treemap leafs are grouped using SVG groups (`<g>`) and borders cannot be added to these elements. If they were SVG `rect`s it would be possible.

As a workaround you can use Highcharts `SVGRenderer` to create them:

```
  var values = chart.series[0].tree.children[4].pointValues,
    left = chart.plotLeft + values.x * chart.plotWidth / 100,
    top = chart.plotTop + values.y * chart.plotHeight / 100,
    width = values.width * chart.plotWidth / 100,
    height = values.height * chart.plotHeight / 100

  var path = chart.renderer.path(['M', left, top, 'l', width, 0, 0, height, -width, 0, 0, -height])
    .attr({
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: 'red',
      zIndex: 3
    })
    .add();
```

**Live working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/Lrhacdvr/

**API reference:** http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

`values` array contains percentage values for group's position and dimensions.

---

**Leaf coloring**

You can use a simple conditional statement while assigning color value for leafs:

```
        causeP = {
          id: countryP.id + '_' + causeI,
          name: causeName[cause],
          parent: countryP.id,
          value: Math.round(+data[region][country][cause])
        };

        if (causeP.name === 'SEC') {
          causeP.color = 'yellow'
        }
```

The above code this is included in the fiddle from *Creating borders* section of this post.

**API reference:**  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.data.color

Comment: Thank you Kamil Kulig for the excellent reply. I worked out some developments from your inputs. Please find my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8kbdph9k/.  I am having two issues 1. I should have a color at each level leaving the last leaf node with the existing color. 2. I am not getting the total summed/average value at the Top Level of the ztree. I kindly request you to help. Thanks in advance

Comment: **1. question:** I don't quite undrstand. Could you prepare some visual example or detailed description of how exactly in this case the leafs should be colored. **2. question:** Do you want to have a total of all the data (MEA, AM, EU...) when you hover on the plot area (tooltip appears)?

Comment: Question 1: Please see the image which will explain you the colouring at each level mean on https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PmevlLPdvt9SgJhZgBgYCR142_mLFjMb ,  Question 2: I want to control the Tool tip at each level and I shuld be able to choose the logic myself what should come at each level, eg: level 0 will be average of the level1, and at level 1 it should be the sum of Level 2 and Level 2 should display anyother custom calculation. I hope I answered your questions. please let me know if I can be of any further information.

Comment: **Q1:** In the example that you provide you have an object counter for each level (`regionI`, `countryI`, `causeI`). You can compare it to the amount of keys in the data (the object iterated using `for in` loop) on this particular level to determine if it's the last point. Then apply the color as I explained in my answer.
**Q2:**  You can create conditional statements and perform computations in `tooltip.pointFormatter`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.tooltip.pointFormatter

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try the same and let you know the feedback. Thank you again.